# How to properly connect a list from the view to the controller using a Model

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to have a form that allows the user to fill in a number of fields that should be condensed to an object when the controller receives them.  I'm having trouble finding the words to explain this so let me give the example.

Basically there are six fields in this object (`AllocationInformation`), which is a part of the model:

```
AllocationInformation
{
    FundSource
    Function
    Location
    Program
    Subject
    Object
}
```

Now the model has a `List<AllocationInformation>` in it.  The view will allow the user the create an arbitrary number of Allocation objects.

So there are six fields in the form, and a button that let's the user add another of the same six fields as many times as they want.

The view also needs to be able to render these objects if they already exist in the model.  I can make all this work, but it's ugly as sin, and I'm hoping to find a better way.

Currently my view is like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addAllocation()">Add Allocation</button>
<div class="row">
    <div id="allocationsDiv" class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-1" id="fundSourceCol">FundSource</div>
            <div class="col-sm-1" id="functionCol">Function</div>
            <div class="col-sm-1" id="locationCol">Location</div>
            <div class="col-sm-1" id="programCol">Program</div>
            <div class="col-sm-1" id="subjectCol">Subject</div>
            <div class="col-sm-1" id="objectCol">Object</div>
            <div class="col-sm-1" id="removeCol">Remove?</div>
        </div>



        @if (Model.Allocations != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Model.Allocations.Count; i++)
            {
                <div>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Allocations[i], new { @class = "form-control input-xsmall" })
                </div>
            }
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the javascript for `addAllocation()`:

```
function addAllocation()
{
    var $row = $("<div class='row'></div>");

    $("#allocationsDiv").append($row);

    var fundSource = "<div class='col-sm-1'><input type='text' name='Allocation.FundSource' class='funding-source-item form-control' /></div>";

    $row.append(fundSource);

    var func = "<div class='col-sm-1'><input type='text' name='Allocation.Function' class='funding-source-item form-control col-sm-1' /></div>";

    $row.append(func);

    var location = "<div class='col-sm-1'><input type='text' name='Allocation.Location' class='funding-source-item form-control col-sm-1' /></div>";

    $row.append(location);

    var program = "<div class='col-sm-1'><input type='text' name='Allocation.Program' class='funding-source-item form-control col-sm-1' /></div>";

    $row.append(program);

    var subject = "<div class='col-sm-1'><input type='text' name='Allocation.Subject' class='funding-source-item form-control col-sm-1' /></div>";

    $row.append(subject);

    var object = "<div class='col-sm-1'><input type='text' name='Allocation.Object' class='funding-source-item form-control col-sm-1' /></div>";

    $row.append(object);

    var $remove = $("<div class='col-sm-1'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove glyphicon-clickable col-sm-1 funding-source-item'></i></div>");

    $remove.on('click', function () {
        $row.remove()
    });

    $row.append($remove);



}
```

And here's where the rub comes in.  The `addAllocation()` function needs to know the current index of how many Allocations have been made so that it builds the input names right, since they should be in the form `Allocation[i].FundSource`, which means I would have to have a global javascript variable or something similar to keep track of it, which just seems like a terrible idea.

I'm just thinking there has to be a way to do this better that I'm not aware of.

Here's the actual `AllocationInformation` class in case it's helpful:

```
public class AllocationInformation
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CheckRequestModel")]
    public int CheckRequestId { get; set; }

    public CheckRequestModel CheckRequestModel { get; set; }

    public string FundSource { get; set; }

    public string Function { get; set; }

    public string Location { get; set; }

    public string Program { get; set; }

    public string Subject { get; set; }

    public string Object { get; set; }

    public float Amount { get; set; }

    public int VendorNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Razor implementation looks good. That should properly postback a `List<AllocationInformation>` object if it's all existing objects.

The problem is with your JavaScript implementation. First, your current JavaScript code doesn't even factor in an index. All the field names are in the form of `Allocation.Foo`. Instead, they need to be in the form of `Allocations[N].Foo` (notice the pluralized form, as well).

Getting the current index is trivial, actually. In your `addAllocation` JavaScript method, just do:

```
var currentIndex = $('#allocationsDiv .row').length - 1;
```

Then, use the `currentIndex` variable in place of the `N` in your field names.

For what it's worth, you may want to consider integrating something like Knockout JS into your project. It makes handling things like rendering collections trivial. You can create a generic "row" template and then bind that template to be rendered for each instance of some observable array. Then, to add or remove rows, you merely need to add or remove items from the array and Knockout updates the HTML accordingly.

**EDIT**

It bears mentioning that the method I gave you to find the current index, only works if items aren't removed out of band. For example, if you start with three items (index 0, 1, and 2), remove the second (index 1), and then add a new one, you'll actually end up with indexes of 0, 2, and 2 again. Obviously that's not going to work. You could attempt to reindex all existing items after removing one, which would entail selecting each row, and updating the name parameters with a new index based on a for loop. However, that's admittedly very clunky. This is another reason why it would behoove you to use something like Knockout JS. All this logic is taken care for you out of the box.

**UPDATE: Knockout Crash Course**

This is how I typically set up the code for my views with Knockout code:

**External JS**

```
var Namespace = Namespace || {};

Namespace.Application = (function () {
    var _init = function (data) {
        var viewModel = Namespace.ViewModel(data);
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        _wireEvents(viewModel);
        return viewModel;
    };

    var _wireEvents = function (viewModel) {
        $('#AddAllocation').on('click', viewModel.AddAllocation);
        $('#Allocations).on('click', '.remove', viewModel.RemoveAllocation);
        // other event handlers here
    };

    return {
        Init: _init
    };
})();

Namespace.ViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = {};

    self.Allocations = ko.observableArray(
        $.map(data.Allocations, Namespace.AllocationViewModel)
    );

    self.AddAllocation = function () {
        self.Allocations.push(new Namespace.AllocationViewModel(Namespace.Allocation));
    };

    self.RemoveAllocation = function () {
        var data = ko.dataFor(this);
        self.Allocations.remove(data);
    };

    return self;
};

Namespace.AllocationViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = {};

    self.Id = ko.observable(data.Id);
    self.CheckRequestId = ko.observable(data.CheckRequestId);
    // etc.

    return self;
};
```

**On-Page JS**

```
<script>
    var Namespace = Namespace || {};

    Namespace.Allocation = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(YourProject.Namespace.To.AllocationInformation));

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var data = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
        Namespace.Application.Init(data);
    });
</script>
```

The `Namespace` variable used here is a generic indication to use a namespace for your application. It's bad form to pollute the global namespace in JavaScript, so you simply create some variable that's unique to your organization, usually something like a company name, and then put all your variables and functions on that object.

The `Namespace.Application` object is the core functionality of the view. You can name it whatever you want; it doesn't have to be called `Application`.

`Namespace.Allocation` is just a JavaScript object representation of the `AllocationInformation` class you have. Storing this allows you to easily add new allocations based on this object template.

`Namespace.ViewModel` is the main Knockout view model, and `Namespace.AllocationViewModel` is a view model specific to a single allocation. The main view model will end up with an observable array of these (via `$.map`).

In this example code, I've created all the observables manually. There's actually a mapping plugin for Knockout that will allow you do something like the following instead:

```
Namespace.ViewModel = function (data) {
    var model = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);

    return model;
}
```

It creates observables automatically for any member of the `data` object. You would then only need to add thing else you needed to the view model, instead of having to spell out each property manually.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer!  I'll definitely have a look at knockout.  I'm not very used to javascript and thinking in terms of actually counting elements in the DOM to get the index, don't know why I didn't think about it.  But nice catch on the edit, I do need to be able to remove them out of band.  Looking up Knockout right now! :)

Comment: So looking at knockoutJS is there a slick way to populate the js viewmodel from the C# viewmodel?  Or do I need to iterate through the C# object in Razor like `@for(int i = 0; i < Model.Allocations.Count; i++) { <text>print out viewmodel for js here</text>}` ?

Comment: That is for the purpose of displaying initial data.  I see how modifications are made after that.

Comment: Jumped the gun on the follow-up, I figured it out.  Thanks again!

Comment: I updated my answer with the typical Knockout code I would employ for something like this.

Comment: Awesome, going through it now

Comment: Ok so for the External JS part, is that intended to be specific for this particular page or is that supposed to be global across the whole site and just assigned to separately for each page's view model?

Comment: No, it should be specific to the view. However, you could probably factor some of it out into more generally applicable pieces. In particular though, the view model would be very page-specific.

Comment: Ok cool, still struggling a bit with the js syntax, but I'm just going to set it up and step through it so I can see what's happening.  Thanks again for all the help